# Return an empty collection when Linq where returns nothing

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, ienumerable

I am using the below statement with the intent of getting all of the machine objects from the `MachineList` collection (type IEnumerable) that have a `MachineStatus` of *i*. The `MachineList` collection will not always contain machines with a status of *i*.

At times when no machines have a `MachineStatus` of *i* I'd like to return an empty collection. My call to `ActiveMachines` (which is used first) works but `InactiveMachines` does not.

```
public IEnumerable<Machine> ActiveMachines
{
    get
    {
        return Customer.MachineList
            .Where(m => m.MachineStatus == "a");
    }
}

public IEnumerable<Machine> InactiveMachines
{
    get
    {
        return Customer.MachineList
            .Where(m => m.MachineStatus == "i");
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Upon further examination it appears that any enumeration of `MachineList` will cause subsequent enumerations of `MachineList` to throw an exeception: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Therefore, it doesn't matter if a call is made to `ActiveMachines` or `InactiveMachines` as its an issue with the `MachineList` collection. This is especially troubling because I can break calls to `MachineList` simply by enumerating it in a Watch before it is called in code. At its lowest level `MachineList` implements `NHibernate.IQuery` being returned as an `IEnumerable`. What's causing `MachineList` to lose its contents after an initial enumeration?

Comment: No, nothing special happens at enumeration; it would be interesting to see what "inactive" etc are in the debugger. I also wonder whether (for example) `MachineStatus` is a facade property that is throwing an exception - i.e. `public string MachineStatus { get {return someInnerField.Status;}}` and `someInnerField` is `null`.

Comment: The real problem is that you're enumerating an `IEnumerable` multiple times. The implicit contract that you agree to when you consume an `IEnumerable` is to enumerate it only once! So the real answer isn't for your coworker to change his code to allow multiple enumeration, but for you to do `Customer.MachineList.ToList()` at some point and then only use the resulting list after that (or, get a new `IEnumerable` again). You can do lazy evaluation; you can cache it, but don't enumerate it twice. You can also expose an `IQueryable` and call it multiple times, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Where` returns an empty sequence if there are no matches; this is a perfectly valid sequence (not null). The only way you'd get a null is if you call `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`.

Are you sure the bug is where you think it is?

```
int?[] nums = { 1, 3, 5 };
var qry = nums.Where(i => i % 2 == 0);
Console.WriteLine(qry == null); // false
Console.WriteLine(qry.Count()); // 0
var list = qry.ToList();
Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // 0
var first = qry.FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(first == null); // true
```

Comment: That's what I thought. I've modified my question to reflect a modification that throws the same error.

Comment: Added some additional information to my question that might shed some light on what's going on. That said, I think I might be bordering on needing to open a new thread.

Comment: The error had to do w/ the way MachineList was being built. I had been consuming this method from another developer and hadn't checked the way it was being built up. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction by asking if I was sure I was looking in the right place.

Answer (score 4):

By default, [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) already does return an empty `IEnumerable<T>`, not null.  If you are seeing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exceptions, it's most likely that something else is the problem.

Is MachineList null, perhaps?  If you hadn't created it, you'd get that exception on your call to `.Where(...)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction by asking if I was sure I was looking in the right place.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, if you wish to explicitly return an empty collection, this can help...

```
Enumerable.Empty<Machine>();
```